# Get info between two custom tags from a html page in vb.net's webbrowser

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

I need a code in vb.net for web browser to extract a information between two custom HTML tags.
Like `<arandomword>MyWord</arandomword>` in `page.html` and and to get `MyWord` .
Something easy please, cause i have only 15 years.
And i'm from Romania and i don't speak english very good.

Comment: What do you mean by "in VB.NET's webbrowser"? Extracting the information as you explained from html file (either from local storage or from online source) is easy, but extracting the same from web browser would be a lot harder I guess..

Comment: From webbrowser ... like webbrowser.documenttitle but with another tags

Comment: okay, seems that you meant [`WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control, not web browser application installed by the user.. check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [`HtmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementsbytagname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method :

```
if (webBrowser1.Document != null)
{
    HtmlElementCollection elems = webBrowser1.Document
                                             .GetElementsByTagName("arandomword");
    string word = elems[0].InnerText;
    ......
}
```